# Why does my AO bake look like this?

Tags: image

[image][image]Why does my AO bake look like this and how can I fix it? Im pretty new to this still.

Thanks!

Comment: please use the editor's button to add images (visible and permanent)

Comment: Sorry for that. :)

Comment: Please add the permanent image, but also please show your World settings tab so we can see the AO settings and the samples - this looks like you forgot to turn it on before baking or that your normals were reversed....

Comment: I added the world tab picture for you.